# mutate string sequence using values from other columns

Tags: r, dictionary, dplyr, tostring

I have a bunch of columns, with starting year and ending year. I need to turn them into sequences based on a "samples per year" column, but not every column has this value, and some only have starting year and no end, so there are lot of "ifs" involved.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
df <- data_frame(first_year = c(1990, 2000, 1987, 1970, 1988),
           last_year = c(2010, 2020, 2004, 2018, NA),
           samples_per_year = c(NA, NA, 4, 2, NA)) 

df %>%
  mutate(middle_years = case_when(is.na(samples_per_year) ~ map2_chr(first_year, last_year, ~ toString(if(!is.na(.y)) .x:.y else .x))))
```

This works for all the rows sampled only once per year, but not for the multiple sampled rows.

I tried adding another case_when and using toString on a `seq()` from first to last sample year using `length_out` to make the sequence longer, but it did not work.

```
df %>%
  mutate(middle_years = case_when(is.na(samples_per_year) ~ map2_chr(first_year, last_year, ~ toString(if(!is.na(.y)) .x:.y else .x)),
                                  !is.na(samples_per_year) ~ map2_chr(first_year, last_year, ~ toString(seq(from=.y,to=.x, length.out = (.y-.x)*samples_per_year)))))
```

Desired output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  first_year last_year samples_per_year middle_years                                            
       <dbl>     <dbl>            <dbl> <chr>                                                   
1       1990      2010             NA 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1…
2       2000      2020             NA 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2…
3       1987      2004              4 1987, 1987.25, 1987.50, 1987.75, 1988, 1988.25, 1988.50...
4       1970      2018              2 1970, 1970.5, 1971, 1971.5, 1972, 1972.5, 1973, 1973.5...                                                      
5       1988        NA             NA 1988
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom sequence function that does this:

```
  my_seq<- function(from, to, mid_len){
      if(is.na(from) & is.na(to)) NA
      else if(is.na(from)) to
      else if(is.na(to)) from 
      else {
         by <- if(is.na(mid_len)) 1 else 1/mid_len
        seq(from, to,by)
      }
  }


df %>% 
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(mid_years = toString(my_seq(first_year, last_year, samples_per_year)))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Rowwise: 
  first_year last_year samples_per_year mid_years                                                          
       <dbl>     <dbl>            <dbl> <chr>                                                              
1       1990      2010               NA 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, ~
2       2000      2020               NA 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, ~
3       1987      2004                4 1987, 1987.25, 1987.5, 1987.75, 1988, 1988.25, 1988.5, 1988.75, 19~
4       1970      2018                2 1970, 1970.5, 1971, 1971.5, 1972, 1972.5, 1973, 1973.5, 1974, 1974~
5       1988        NA               NA 1988
```